# Return a boolean value from a select query

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I would like to select boolean value:

```
SELECT field1, field2, 1 as is_field
FROM TABLE
```

In Visual Studio 2010 I am doing:

```
bool b = row.Field<bool>("is_field");
```

But I get the exception:

> Specified cast is not valid.

How can I return a boolean value as `boolean` and not as `int`?

Comment: There isn't a boolean data type in SQL Server/Transact SQL. The closest is bit, which AdaTheDev is guiding you towards - but there's no means to specify a bit literal - you have to supply a literal of a different data type and convert it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From SQL side, you can do:

```
SELECT field1, field2, CAST(1 AS BIT) AS is_field
FROM TABLE
```

to force it to be returned as a BIT instead of an int. That should do the trick

**Update:**
What is your concern for using CAST like this? SQL Server is pretty awesome at optimising e.g. the execution plan for above query would show is_field is a Constant which can be evaluated once up front (there's a related article here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175933.aspx). Even without that, if you're concerned about performance, then you shouldn't worry about it - it would very much be premature optimisation.

Comment: @Naor - you either need to return it as a BIT from SQL and leave your .NET code as-is.....or leave your SQL as-is and change your .NET code to do something like: 

bool b = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Field<int>("is_field"));

Comment: I would like to return it as bit from the sql without using cast. I don't care return "true" or something like that instead of 1 as long as it is bool.

Comment: @Naor - final option to not have an explicit CAST is:
`DECLARE @True BIT
SET @True = 1
SELECT field1, field2, @True AS is_field
...`

Comment: @Naor - did that help you (my last comment)? Which matches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090186/return-bit-constant-from-sql-stored-procedure

Comment: I am using a view and not stored procedure. Therefore I cannot declare @True variable.

Comment: @Naor: Then you'll have to choose either changing your SQL code or changing your client code, as you've already been advised. So far there seems to be no way to change the fact that `1` without casting is treated as `int`. Check this: `SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(1, 'BaseType')`.

Comment: @Naor - then there are no more options I'm afraid (without actual performance hits). Please see the update in my answer - you shouldn't be concerned about performance of this, if that is your issue.

Answer (score 4):

Per @AdaTheDev's suggestion:

```
bool b = row.Field<int>("is_field") == 1;
```