# Return BIT constant from SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, casting, sqldatatypes

OK, I'm trying to return a BIT constant from a Stored Procedure.

The only way I've managed to get this to compile is using a cast:

`CAST(0 AS BIT) AS MyBool`

Is there a more efficient way to write this without a cast?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088577/return-a-boolean-value-from-a-select-query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some people prefer to do the following

```
declare @True bit,@False bit
set @True = 1
set @False = 0
```

And then use `@True` or `@False` for the remainder of their query.

I would imagine that post compilation the difference in efficiency between the two methods is so vanishingly small you can safely write it in whatever style you prefer.

Comment: Not really an option when you are writing a view.

Answer (score 1):

Not as far as I know.
When infering data types SQL server does some magic, but it usually errs on the side of caution, so

```
Select 0
```

will always select an integer, never a bit or a tinyint