# Getting a boolean from a SELECT in SQL Server into a bool in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have this code in my SELECT:

```
SELECT  A.CompletedDate,
    CASE
        WHEN (@AdminTestId IS NULL AND @UserTestId IS NULL) THEN 0
        WHEN (@AdminTestId = temp.AdminTestId AND @UserTestId = A.UserTestId) THEN 1
        WHEN (@AdminTestId = temp.AdminTestId AND @UserTestId IS NULL) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END AS [Current],
```

and in my ASP.NET DTO I have:

```
public partial class GetTestsDTO
{
    public bool? GradePass { get; set; }
    // the following line is what is giving the error. If I remove
    // the line it will not try to convert the data and there is no
    // error. Note that I want to put this into a bool as web.api
    // then passes it to the client as a bool
    public bool Current { get; set; } 
    public DateTime? CompletedDate { get; set; }
}
```

It's giving me an error and I would appreciate some help.

The error is:

> message=The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to
>   the 'System.Boolean' type is not valid.

Comment: Maybe that's because you're returning an integer?

Comment: `CAST( 0 AS BIT)` and  `CAST(1 AS BIT)`?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't *have* an exposed boolean data type, so you're not returning one in a `SELECT`. As lad suggests though, it does have a `bit` data type and ADO.Net supports converting *those* into booleans.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088577/return-a-boolean-value-from-a-select-query

Comment: @lad2025 - I tried your suggestion and it worked good. If you would like to add this as an answer I can accept.  Thanks

Comment: You can use the `Convert`-Class => Convert.ToBool(); See https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/wh2c31dd(v=vs.110).aspx for details

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The easiest way (SQL Server side) is to convert values `0` and `1` to [`BIT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx) datatype:

```
SELECT  A.CompletedDate,
  CASE
    WHEN (@AdminTestId IS NULL AND @UserTestId IS NULL) 
    THEN CAST(0 AS BIT)
    WHEN (@AdminTestId = temp.AdminTestId AND @UserTestId = A.UserTestId) 
    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
    WHEN (@AdminTestId = temp.AdminTestId AND @UserTestId IS NULL) 
    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
   ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
  END AS [Current],
```

or entire expression at once:

```
SELECT  A.CompletedDate,
    CAST((CASE
         WHEN (@AdminTestId IS NULL AND @UserTestId IS NULL) THEN 0
         WHEN (@AdminTestId = temp.AdminTestId AND @UserTestId = A.UserTestId) THEN 1
         WHEN (@AdminTestId = temp.AdminTestId AND @UserTestId IS NULL) THEN 1
         ELSE 0
         END)
         AS BIT) AS [Current],
```

---

[SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
╔═════════════════════════════════╦═════════════════════╦═══════════════════════╗
║ SQL Server Database Engine type ║ .NET Framework type ║ SqlDbType enumeration ║
╠═════════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╣
║ bit                             ║ Boolean             ║ Bit                   ║
╚═════════════════════════════════╩═════════════════════╩═══════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 4):

As noted in the comments you are returning an integer. You need to return a `bit`, which ASP.NET will understand as a Boolean.

```
SELECT A.CompletedDate,
  CASE
      WHEN (@AdminTestId IS NULL AND @UserTestId IS NULL) THEN 
        CONVERT(bit, 0)
      WHEN (@AdminTestId = temp.AdminTestId AND @UserTestId = A.UserTestId) THEN
         CONVERT(bit, 1)
      WHEN (@AdminTestId = temp.AdminTestId AND @UserTestId IS NULL) THEN
         CONVERT(bit, 1)
      ELSE
         CONVERT(bit, 0)
  END AS [Current],
```

Or as pointed out [Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever) in the comments below, you could wrap the whole `CASE` statement in a `CONVERT`.

```
SELECT A.CompletedDate,
  CONVERT(bit, 
    CASE
      WHEN (@AdminTestId IS NULL AND @UserTestId IS NULL) THEN 0
      WHEN (@AdminTestId = temp.AdminTestId AND @UserTestId = A.UserTestId) THEN 1
      WHEN (@AdminTestId = temp.AdminTestId AND @UserTestId IS NULL) THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END
  ) AS [Current],
```

You could also use `CAST(1 AS bit)` and `CAST(0 AS bit)` in replace of `CONVERT(bit, 1)` and `CONVERT(bit, 0)` respectively (see [T-SQL Cast versus Convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707335/t-sql-cast-versus-convert) for more information).

You could also perform the conversion client-side:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        var dto = new GetTestsDTO();
        dto.Current = Convert.ToBoolean(reader.GetInt32(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it can be necessary to set the convert also for the 0 in the else statement because also the 0 is an integer not a boolean.

Comment: Done. I noticed it soon as I saved the answer!

Comment: Or just do the `CONVERT` once, outside the `CASE` rather than within each `THEN`.

Answer (score 1):

As the previous comments suggest, SQL cannot return the "boolean" value, and you are not returning it either.

My suggestion/solution (that I use, and have seen used everywhere I worked) is to simply recover that Integer in your object, and then use a 'map' function that will transform that Integer to a Boolean.

The (simple) method will do something like this (attention; Java version ahead):

```
public static boolean integerToBoolean(Integer myInt){
     return myInt == 1 ? true : false;
}
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Or just use the [Convert.ToBoolean(Int32) method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0b8dwce(v=vs.110).aspx)